# What is a remote controlled "toy" car legally in Europe, especially Germany?

Tags: european-union, germany, car, autonomous

I was wondering in which way remote controlled "toy" cars are treated from law side in the European Union and especially Germany while being on public (play) streets or sidewalks.

I put "toy" in quotes, because I am mostly interested in the bigger ones used e.g. in sports/ competitions.

Searching the web, I came to [REGULATION (EU) No 168/2013 OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL of 15 January 2013 on the approval and market surveillance of two- or three-wheel vehicles and quadricycles](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2013:060:0052:0128:EN:PDF).

Based on this, I would say that they are vehicle category L6e-A, but these would e.g. require a suitable driving license and type approval, which is not appearently both not required for these kind of cars.

Comment: Is your toy faster than 6 km/h and equipped with a seat? Otherwise the EU regulation doesn't apply. "treated from law side" is very broad. Can you be more specific?

Comment: What are "*public (play) streets*"?

Comment: @Rick This came from dict.leo.org. In German they are called "Spielstraße", where children are allowed to play and cars have to drive very very slow and take care for them.

Comment: @Roland The ones for the children are probably not faster than 6km/h. However, I never clocked them. The ones they use in competitions for sure are much faster than that. The fastest RC car I have ever read of can at least drive 100 km/h.
Seats, at least ones in which humans fit, for sure they do not have due to their size.

I did not want to write type approval here, because there could be e.g. requirements for self certification.
The question is at the end, if an accident happens or something like that, which laws are applied.

Comment: "Spielstraße" is colloquial. The official term is "Verkehrsberuhigter Bereich" (traffic-calmed area).

Comment: ["Spielstrasse"](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spielstra%C3%9Fe) has an own sign: red circle plus white rectangle with child and ball, not the blue rectangle with children, ball, car and house of ["Verkehrsberuhigter Bereich"](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsberuhigter_Bereich). But most germans will point by saying "Spielstrasse" onto the blue sign...

Comment: @Roland Seat definitively not, at least not one in which a human fits. When it comes to the speed, this would go in the direction of the question. Depending on relevant regulations, this might need to be proofed in some way, perhaps even checked by an accredited third party. Even tuning protection might be required to ensure one cannot get beyond the 6km/h.